# Bootstrap Navbar left fixed is not fixed

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3

I'ld like to use a bootstrap navigation on the left.
And while scrolling the main contant it shout stay left.
I tried to copy http://www.bootply.com/90936
But in my case it looks like that http://www.mehlhop.com/gesim/gcode_specifications.html.
The Menu is not fixed.
Does somebody hase a idea why it does not stay on the left side?

Frank

Answer (score 0):

I may figured out how to make the navbar work as you want:

Remove this from your inline css on the top:

```
.affix-top,.affix{position: static;}
```

Let me know if it is as you wanted.

Comment: I want to fix it left, not top!

Comment: you have to remove it

Comment: Makes no difference.

Comment: I can see that you didn't remove it, by the way on my pc if i remove it,It works properly..